# Word for an object tied to a rope

Tags: single-word-requests

Ropes are usually tied to two things, a stabilized object (doesn't move) and an object that is dynamic (able to move).

For example, a boat is tied to a dock, the dock is the stabilized object and the boat is the dynamic object. Another example is a hanging chandelier, the ceiling is the stabilized object and the chandelier is the dynamic object.

In the above examples, it would be appropriate to call the dock/ceiling the anchor, but what do you call the boat/chandelier?

**I'll tie the rope to the anchor, you tie it to the ____**

Comment: The tethered object? The object to be restrained?  In practice one just calls it whatever it is, the boat, the horse, the chandelier.  You’d only need a hypernym when writing the instruction book for the rope.

Comment: Actually, calling the fixed end the "anchor" is apt to be confusing, especially in a nautical context.  As to what to call the hanging thing, it de[pendant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pendant)s.

Comment: Ropes are usually tied to two things and that's not the point. Whether anything is "stabilised" is not the point.

If you must go down that route no, the dock isn't "stabilised"; it's "stable", as is your ceiling. Doesn't the difference matter?

That a boat or a chandelier happen to be unconstrained except by the rope doesn't make either "dynamic", though both are "moveable". 

If you're trying to make a comparison with ropes and anchors, I suggest neither docks nor ceilings could ever fill your bill.

Could you rephrase it so "you tie it to the ___" had something useful to work on?

Comment: @Jim I'm using this term for programming. Therefore, it needs to be directly obvious what it is referring too.

Comment: @GaryHoliday  class TetherableObject extends Object ...   TetherableObjects have  a TetherPoint...

Answer (score 0):

A free end with nothing attached to it is a tail or running end.  The fixed end is the "standing end". The other end is the "working end" when you are knotting. The bit left after tying a knot is the tag. See igkt.net or netknots.com.

Specifically, an anchor rode has a bitter end - it's fastened to the bitts or wound round them

> "A Bitter is but the turne of a Cable about the Bits, and veare it out by little and little. And the Bitters end is that part of the Cable doth stay within boord."
>
> Seaman's Grammar, 1627, by Captain Smith, which is the earliest
>   citation of the phrase in print

https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/the-bitter-end.html